# Need help in codeigniter pagination

Tags: codeigniter, pagination

I am using codeignietr pagination.  I am facing a problem here.
The pagination numbers are coming in the page, but it is always fixed. Means if have total 8 pages, then I will click 5th page and it is going to the 5th page but from there if i click the next link it is not going to the 6th page, instead it is going to the 2nd page(**the 1st page is always fixed or highlighted**).
Currently If i click any page, only first page link only highlighting. I am expecting a code to highlight respective link on clicking on it.

Comment: we are expecting some code too!

Comment: pagination config "base url" is set wrong, or wrong uri segment is set.

Comment: or the total rows the pagination config are receiving is wrong

Comment: @tomexsans I doublt, because it would generate "less" or "more" pages to click on. What I mean OP may have set wrong total rows but if he has at least 2 pages of results this error is not spotable. It would generate only "`$per_page`" => 1 page to click OP has 8 to click - If OP uses `count()` on returned SQL query. So generated links are wrong I assume OP is intelligent enough to calculate "total rows/perpage" = number of pages generated...

Comment: @Kyslik we may never know, without the code

Comment: I strongly agree with you, I am crafting an answer I think it will help OP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello please set your `$pagi_config['base_url']` correct.

Also please count correctly and set up `$pagi_config['uri_segment']` correctly

in this particular case `http://localhost/project_folder/articles //correctly set .htaccess + index.php removed is assumed`

```
$pagi_config['base_url'] = base_url('articles/page'); //note that base_url() function is in url helper
$pagi_config['uri_segment'] = '3';
```

Please note that `index()` method in any controller does **NOT** accept any parameters! Anything written after controller name is considered as its method!

Also note that number generated by pagination library is not page number! It is offset!

Either use [`_remap()`](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/general/controllers.html#remapping), or [routes.php](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html) to make `articles/<offset>`, in routes case you still need extra method to take care of offset parameter.

Comment: @Kyslik..Thanksfor your answer..It worked for me..The problem was with $pagi_config['uri_segment'].  In my case it should be 2...Once again thanks for your help..

Answer (score 0):

On this part:

> I am expecting a code to highlight respective link on clicking on it

Based on [Codeigniter's docs](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/libraries/pagination.html), it should be something like this in your `controller`.

```
$config['num_tag_open']   = '<div class="current">';
$config['num_tag_close']  = '</div>';
```

You can than create a css style for `.current` and then whatever page you are on, the number will be styled.